# util.inherits in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am working on a Node.js server and I am using coffee script to develop.

How does this work on coffee script?

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

util.inherits(Connector, EventEmitter)
```

Is it?

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

class @Connector extends EventEmitter
```

I am basically trying to add `emit` to `Connector`.
Something like:

```
this.emit('online')
```

Comment: We need more context, what's `util`?

Comment: which is not valid syntax?

Comment: It is valid, I'm referring to `inherits`. What you can do is compare the compiled code, and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: I updated the question for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So are you having problems? Any errors in console? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If you want to see if `inherits` does the same as `extends` in Coffee, compile the code, and compare it against the JavaScript version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`extends`](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) does a similar thing as [`util.inherits`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).

[Implementation of `util.inherits`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/95dbb6bf647d90947c0c738533dadf391559be98/lib/util.js#L615):

```
inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
    ctor.super_ = superCtor;
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: ctor,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
};
```

[Compilation of `extends`](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20%40Connector%20extends%20EventEmitter):

```
var __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent) {
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key))
            child[key] = parent[key];
    }
    function ctor() {
        this.constructor = child;
    }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
};

function Connector() {
    return Connector.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
__extends(Connector, EventEmitter);
```

The differences are:

- The exact name of the `super` property on the child constructor
- `util.inherits` uses `Object.create` while `extends` does use an ES3-compatible version
- `util.inhirits` makes the `constructor` property of the child constructor non-enumerable
- `extend` copies "static" properties of the parent constructor onto the child constructor
- The `extends` keyword automatically [calls the super constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22791368/1048572) if no `constructor` is given for the class