# One object doesn't listen to an event emitted on another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

Trying to make an object emitting and receiving events:

```
var events = require('events'),
    util   = require('util');

function Obj(){
  events.EventEmitter.call( this ); // what does this line?
}

util.inherits( Obj, events.EventEmitter );

var o = new Obj(),
    a = new Obj();

a.on('some', function () {
  console.log('a => some-thing happened');
});

o.on('some', function () {
  console.log('o => some-thing happened');
});

o.emit('some');
```

- having a response `o => some-thing happened` only from the same object but not another. Why? And how to make them both to listen `some` event?
- What `events.EventEmitter.call( this );` line does? It doesnt make any difference to result. Taken from http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Comment: If you would have asked two separate questions, I could have closed the second as a [duplicate of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22791368/1048572)…

Comment: yeap, found this one. yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> having a response `o => some-thing happened` only from the same object but not another. Why?

Because they're different emitter objects. Each emitter notifies only its own listeners; it's an observer pattern not a mediator one.

> And how to make them both to listen `some` event?

Use only a single `EventEmitter` instance. You might not even need that `Obj` subclass, just do `a = o = new EventEmitter()`.

> What `events.EventEmitter.call( this );` line does? It doesnt make any difference to result.

See [What is the difference between these two constructor patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22791368/1048572)

Comment: Observer means that you are listening to a specific observable - and you have two of them, only one of them is emitting an event. Mediator would mean that you have a global object on which all others are listening and/or firing events.

Answer (score 0):

1. They are separate event emitting objects, the only thing `inherits()` does is sets the prototype of the subclass to be that of the prototype of the parent. Subclasses are not magically linked together.
2. `events.EventEmitter.call( this );` executes the parent's constructor to allow it to perform some initialization of its own (for example, setting up the event listeners object that stores event handlers for events and other properties). Then after `events.EventEmitter.call( this );` you can perform your own initialization for your subclass on top of that. This typically includes properties that are instance specific (e.g. `this.id = Math.random() * 1000`);